# Migrating SafetyNet to Play Integrity API for Firebase

Tags: firebase, google-developers-console, safetynet, google-play-integrity-api

I'm developing a flutter application which uses Firebase as its framework. One of Firebase's features that we use is App Check. I've been using SafetyNet for my Android App Check, but recently I've gotten an email from Google that states that SafetyNet will be discontinued and developers are recommended to migrate to Play Integrity. The problem is, I don't know how to do so, I've tried changing it directly from Firebase Console, and now both my Play Integrity and SafetyNet option is checked, last time it was only SafetyNet. Are there any steps that I might've missed? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Were you able to figure this out? I know you have to link your project on Google Play Console (Setup > App Integrity).

Comment: It requires more work than simply ticking boxes. It especially requires you to call some APIs from your app. I recommend you start on [this documentation page](https://developer.android.com/google/play/integrity/overview). If the text scares you, scroll down to the graph that shows how the different actors (including your app and your own API) interact.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the follwing line to your build.gradle ?

```
implementation 'com.google.android.play:integrity:1.3.0'
```

Read more at [Developers](https://developer.android.com/google/play/integrity/setup)